# Have CKeditor use custom model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a setup where only one table is used for files including ckeditor. As it stands I am using the default with table that is generated when using the ckeditor gems install method from the console.
I have been through all of the documentation and have yet to find a way to customize the model that is being used. I did however find in "config/initializers/ckeditor.rb"
In this file is the following commented out lines

```
# Asset model classes
# config.picture_model { Ckeditor::Picture }
# config.attachment_file_model { Ckeditor::AttachmentFile }
```

I want to make it work off of a polymorphic table that I created for all file uploades to use, image below.

[image]

Would I just change the code to look like the following or is going to take something more.

```
# Asset model classes
config.picture_model { Media}
config.attachment_file_model { Media}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be enough.

Have a look ckeditor's [asset model](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/active_record/carrierwave/ckeditor/asset.rb). The model needs to include `Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase`.

Then check ckeditor's [table](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/generators/ckeditor/templates/active_record/carrierwave/migration.rb). The fields in your `Media` model has different fields.

Therefore, you have to make your `Media` model and table compatible with ckeditor.